# Getting build error when overriding method

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, msbuild-task

When running the build process in a pipeline in Azure DevOps I get errors saying 'no suitable method to override'. The error is on all OnInitialized and OnParametersSet methods on the project.

No changes has been made in those methods since the last build.

Tried to rerun the pipeline with the code before the last commit -> still same errors.
Tried to compile locally in Visual Studio - no errors.
Tried to publish directly from VS to the web app - no problem.

Comment: This is probably CS0115 error code, check the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0115

Comment: Yes it is but it can build locally so this is not the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build pipeline in Devops - make sure that the .Net SDK is not set to 7.0.X as this will currently install version 7.0.302 which seems to fail when building Blazor projects.
Hard code the SDK to 7.0.203 and the build should work!